# How to exclude certain posts from showing up in wp_query if the post data does not fit parameters?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am fairly new to PHP so this might be a simple fix. I am editing a plugin and trying to modify it to where, based on a set of inputs, I want to output only certain posts whose metadata fits the parameters of the inputs and not show posts whose data does not fit. How would I exclude posts whose data does not fit in the output?

I have already done everything up to this point but am stuck at where if the inputted data does not fit in the post meta data it does not display. I am guessing I would need to use a `$_post == null` function and have tried many variations of that, but nothing has worked.

The is the line of code I am stuck on:

```
<?php if ( $creditscore >= esc_attr($min_credit_score) ) { echo "good";} else { $_Post == null; ;
} ?>
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php htmlspecialchars($_GET["crd"]);
?>


<?php 

    $args = array(   
    'post_type' => 'lenders',   
    'posts_per_page' => $number1,
    'lender_cat' => 'personal-loans',

);  
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();     
$advertised_title = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_cmb_advertised_title', true);
$advertised_number = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_cmb_advertised_number', true);
$comparison_title = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_cmb_comparison_title', true);
$comparison_number = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_cmb_comparison_number', true);
$min_credit_score = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_cmb_min_credit_score', true);
$btn_text = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_cmb_btn_text', true);
$btn_link = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_cmb_btn_link', true);
$except = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_cmb_except', true);
$creditscore = htmlspecialchars($_GET["crd"], true);

?>

     <?php if ( $creditscore >= esc_attr($min_credit_score) ) { echo "goodtest";} else { wp_query == null; ;
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `$creditscore` value to your `WP_Query`. Check the documentation for [Custom Field (post meta) Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters)

i.e.

```
$creditscore = htmlspecialchars($_GET["crd"], true);

$args = [
    'post_type' => 'lenders',   
    'posts_per_page' => $number1,
    'category_name' => 'personal-loans',
    'meta_query' => [
        [
            'key'     => '_cmb_min_credit_score',
            'value'   => $creditscore,
            'compare' => '<=',
        ],
    ],
]; 

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

**Notes**: Since you mentioned you're new to PHP I'll add some notes.

1. Depending on the PHP version you're using you can use `$var = []` for arrays. If that syntax throws errors keep using `$var = array()`
2. I added the comparison with the credit score in the Query, so you don't retrieve results you don't need.
3. I changed the `lender_cat` for `category_name`, since that's the way to use the `WP_Query`
4. There are elegant ways to debug your code, but a simple check is to `var_dump` or `print_r` your results to check if you're getting them

i.e.

```
<?php

while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    print_r($post);
endwhile;
```

Give it a try and let us know!